# I am trying to create a shell script that will notify me (not email) if certain users log on to a linux machine

Tags: bash

Basically I have a list of user names in a text file that I need to watch. All i need is a simple script to notify me if they log on to the system, but not email me.

Comment: It would be better if you clarified how you want to be notified. All logins are normally tracked by syslog so you can always look in /var/log/messages to find out who logged in

Comment: A pop up and audible alert would be cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a brute force solution, using SSH to connect to the server if you specify a `user@host` combo, or it checks to local machine. It assumes passwordless public-key access and it uses the `last` command to poll the last logged on user every 30s.
The command `notify-send` is used for the pop-up which assumes a desktop Linux machine.

```
#!/bin/sh
host=$1
while true; do
  if [ "$host" ]; then
    last_user=`ssh $host last`
  else
    last_user=`last`
  fi
  last_user=`echo $last_user | head -n1 | awk '{ print $1,$2,$3 }'`
  if [ "$last_user" != "$previous_user" ]; then
    notify-send $last_user
    previous_user=$last_user
  fi
  sleep 30
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [notify-send](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/notify-send.1.html) which would do this. You would have to script logins into notify-send, which in turn would put a notification bubble on screen.